# Replacing torch/flashlight battery with power adapter

Tags: power-supply

I own a torch/flashlight which requires a 26650 2000mAh rechargeable battery.

I'd like to power it with a power adapter, but all I can find here is 3V or 4.5V so it's either too low or too high.

EDIT: 26650 rechargeable battery is 3,6V - 3,7V

Comment: You must specify current with voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some options to choose from:

**Option 1 - Lower power**

Go with the 3V power supply and the torch will like still work (maybe not at full brightness)

**Option 2 - Regulate it down**

Get a power supply with a higer voltage and regulate it using either a linear voltage regulator or a DC-DC buck regulator.

**Option 3 - Drop voltage with diode**

Get the 4.5V power supply and place a diode in series, which will drop about 0.7V making it 3.8V which should be fine for the torch.